# Can I have a conditional shebang?

Tags: linux, shebang

I have a script that can be run with different interpreters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env default-interpreter
[my script]
```

But I would like to use an `alternative-interpreter` if it's available, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env alternative-interpreter
[my script]
```

Is there a way to create a shebang that looks for `alternative-interpreter` and falls back to `default-interpreter` in case the first one isn't available?

Comment: Quoting someones' suggestion here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070516/conditional-shebang-line-for-different-versions-of-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not directly, no.  Best to write a wrapper Bourne shell script and shebang that:

```
#!/path/to/my/wrapper
```

and the wrapper starts with:

```
#!/bin/sh
for shell in first second third; do
    if /usr/bin/env "${shell}" "$@"; do exit $?; done
done
# We didn't find any of them.
exit 1
```

This lets env(1) use the ${PATH} search list to locate the programs, in the order given in the for-loop.

Comment: Nice idea. But what if I don't know the `/path/to/first` and `path/to/second` is there still a way to use `/usr/bin/env` to redirect script execution?

Comment: If the command exists but fails it will still run the second then the third program.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example to run a python script using `python|python3|python2` whichever is first available.
This is craftable by interpreting some tokens in `python|shell` differently.

1. First it takes advantage of docstring comment token `'''`, which makes the crafting much easier. And `'''` can be easily ignore in shell interpreter by adding another `'`.
2. Then since both syntaxes accept `#` as a comment, so we can wrap the enclosing `EOF` with `#`, i.e. `#EOF`, which is syntax-correct and functionality-correct in both shell interpreter and python interpreter.

Even more, you can safely pass all args using `"$@"`:

```
#!/bin/sh
#crafted to dynamically select python version, while keeping the script part fully compatible to python syntax so it won't break any IDE/syntax highlighting.
'''w'hich python>/dev/null && PYTHON_EXE=`which python` || { which python3>/dev/null && PYTHON_EXE=`which python3`; } || { which python2>/dev/null && PYTHON_EXE=`which python2`; } || { echo python is not available in PATH!; exit 1; }
$PYTHON_EXE - "$@" <<EO'F'''
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
print("Hello World")
print(sys.argv)

#EOF
```

Comment: Upvoted - don't know why this was downvoted. This is more or less what SaltStack does.

Comment: I adapted this answer to write a Python script that selects the Salt-installed Python executable (which varies across platforms):

`#!/bin/sh` (newline)
`"""$(dirname $(which salt-ssh))"/bin/python3 - "$@" <<"EOF"""`